# Angular 2+: How to programmatically add styles to child components that generate html?

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I have the following situation:
I created a component that uses a 3rd-party component which then uses a JS library (for charts) which then generates HTML/SVG I need to style from my component.

So we have something like

(MyComponent) => (3rdPartyComponent) => (JSLibrary) => Dynamically generated HTML/SVG

The generated SVG is looking something like this:

```
<svg><g class="labels">...</g></svg>
```

Because there can be multiple charts on a single page MyComponent might be instantiated multiple times and styling can be different for every generated SVG.

I now want to change the font-size of the chart labels programmatically according to some @Input to MyComponent, e.g. `useSmallLables`.

How can I do that?

More details.
Here's want I want in (not working) pseudo-code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: '<third-party [ngClass]="getCssClasses()" ...></third-party>",
  style: ''
})
export class MyComponent ... {
  @Input() useSmallLabels = false;

  // we need a unique class name to be able to apply styles to a specific SVG, not all
  uniqueCssClass = generateSomeUniqueId();

  getCssClasses() {
    const cssOptions = {};

    // add the unique class
    cssOptions[this.uniqueCssClass] = true;

    // This it what I would like to do, but of course does not work with ngClass or anything else as far I know.
    // We would need ::ng-deep as the generated SVG does not know about angular emulated shadow-dom attributes and vice-versa
    const css = '::ng-deep .' + this.uniqueCssClass + ' .labels { font-size: 0.5rem; }';
    cssOptions[css] = this.useSmallLabels;

    return cssOptions;
}
```

I digged really deep to find out some way to manage this, but I never found a solution. With old-school JQuery and stuff this probably wouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution that works for me:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: '<third-party [ngClass]="getCssClasses()" ...></third-party>",
  style: '.small-labels ::ng-deep .label { font-size: 0.5rem; }'
})
export class MyComponent ... {
  @Input() useSmallLabels = false;

  // we need a unique class name to be able to apply styles to a specific SVG, not all
  uniqueCssClass = generateSomeUniqueId();

  getCssClasses() {
    const cssOptions = {};

    // add the unique class
    cssOptions[this.uniqueCssClass] = true;

    // this activates or deactivates the ::ng-deep CSS style 
    cssOptions['small-labels] = this.useSmallLabels;

    return cssOptions;
}
```

When you have the solution it suddenly looks like a very easy problem...

We still have problem here that `::ng-deep` is deprecated now so I'll need another workaround when Angular drops it.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot add the actual styles to `ngClass` directive, just class names. You could create a style tag dynamically (seems to be ok https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#template-inline-styles) and add the logic there:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-component',
    template: `
        <style *ngIf="uniqueCssClass && useSmallLabels">
            .{{ uniqueCssClass }} ::ng-deep .labels {
                font-size: 0.5rem;
            }
        </style>
        <third-party [ngClass]="getCssClasses()"></third-party>"
    `,
    style: ''
})
export class MyComponent ... {
    @Input() useSmallLabels = false;

    // we need a unique class name to be able to apply styles to a specific SVG, not all
    uniqueCssClass = generateSomeUniqueId();

    getCssClasses() {
        return this.uniqueCssClass;
    }
}
```

I am not sure if `::ng-deep` works with inline styles. If it doesn't remove `::ng-deep` and try to set viewEncapsulation of the component to none (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation). But be aware that the style scope will become global so wrap your component and styles to some class. Also I am not sure how viewEncapsulation behaves together with inline styles.

Comment: Inline styles are a great tip, but I tried it out and it does not work: On the one hand, because `{{ uniqueCssClass }}` does not work with inline styles and on the other hand also ::ng-deep seems to disappear in the generated CSS (though I don't actually know what Angular _should_ generate out of ::ng-deep in real-world CSS... /deep/?).

Comment: Angular have a place for styles, which isn't inside the template. That's a hack.

Comment: Like i said, angular documentation mentions inline styles in templates so I wouldn't consider that as a hack. I understand why inline style in general are bad idea, but I can't think anything else to add styling to dynamically generated classes.